# How to replace div content for dynamically generated content with EJS?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, wysiwyg, ejs

I have a dynamically generated blog posts with EJS and Node.js. I am using WYSYWIG editor on the backend and the post content is being stored in MongoDB as a string with html tags. On the frontend I need to escape string and render html tags for each post but my solution takes all div with blog_content class and replaces all of them with the content of the first post.

```
<section id="blog" class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <% for(var i=0; i<blogOBJ.length; i++) {%>
            <!-- First Blog Post -->
            <div class="cont">
                <h2>
                    <a href="#"><%= blogOBJ[i].post_title %></a>
                </h2>
                <p class="lead by_author">
                    by <a href="index.php"><%= blogOBJ[i].post_author %></a>
                </p>
                <p><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> Posted on <%= blogOBJ[i].post_date %></p>
                <hr>
                <p class="blog_content"><%= blogOBJ[i].post_content %></p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Read More <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
            </div>
        <% } %>
            <!-- Pager -->
            <ul class="pager">
                <li class="previous">
                    <a href="#">&larr; Older</a>
                </li>
                <li class="next">
                    <a href="#">Newer &rarr;</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</section><!--/#blog-->
```

and my jQuery:

```
var text= $('.blog_content').text();
$('.blog_content').html(now).text();
```

Comment: Not sure I get it? Is the EJS part relevant at all, or is it just that the jQuery code replaces all the posts with the content of the first one ?

Comment: you right, ejs is not relevant at all, my problem is that blog post divs have the same class and jQuery is replacing all divs content with the ontent of the first div.

Comment: So you want to get the text from each blog post, and then replace the HTML with the text only ?

Comment: Have you tried just doing `<%- blogOBJ[i].post_content %>`

Comment: this is exactly what I have in the div content, Blog post is a string containing html tags that need to be rendered to style the content otherwise it the text would be on block

Comment: That's not what you have in the code above, there's a slight difference in what I posted in that it doesn't escape the HTML tags.

Comment: I just solved it with this code  $( ".blog_content" ).each(function( index ) {
    var content = $( this ).text();
    $( this ).html(content).text();
});

Comment: Good for you, I don't see why you wouldn't just output the HTML unescaped instead, but whatever floats your goat.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with `$('.blog_content')` you select all items that have the class `.blog_content`. You need to select only one at a time and change them one at a time with the needed data for each case.
 `$('.blog_content')` will return an array-like object, and you can access items in it, like  `$('.blog_content')[i]`. You should be able to isolate your item and update only what you want.

Comment: this worked for me perfectly, I don't know why I haven't thought about it before, THANKS

Comment: $( ".blog_content" ).each(function( index ) {
    var content = $( this ).text();
    $( this ).html(content).text();
});